# Rewrite with mod_rewrite even folder is exists

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I use `mod_rewrite` to route css files to my css minify php file.
this is my `.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule template/(.*)/css/(.*)$ css.php?css=$1/css/$2 [L]
```

the sample url is : `template/default/css/main.css`
but because this folder is exists, the `mod_rewrite` will not work and load that css file directly !

What should I do ?

UPDATE :

Full .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 module.php?mod=error
RewriteRule template/(.*)/css/(.*)$ css.php?css=$1/css/$2 [L]
RewriteRule index.html$ ./index.php
RewriteRule (.*).html$ ./module.php?mod=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule (.*)/$ ./module.php?mod=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Is this your complete .htaccess? If not post the full .htaccess here in your question.

Comment: I updated my question with full .htaccess code

Comment: So this URL: `http://domainc.com/css.php?css=default/css/main.css` loads css correctly?

Comment: Yes, this url load minified css file

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

ErrorDocument 404 module.php?mod=error

RewriteRule ^template/([^/]+/css/.+)$ css.php?css=$1 [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^index\.html$ index.php [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ module.php?mod=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: When I insert this code I will get 500 Internal server error, I added just `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews` to my old htaccess and the problem is related to this line

Comment: Please check your apache error and see what error are you getting there.

Comment: I just tested this code and it worked fine in my Apache server.